# jQuery checkbox trigger change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JS function:

```
const bindSwitches = function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".lever", function() {
    var checkbox = $(this).siblings("input[type=checkbox]");
    var hiddenField = $(this).siblings("input[type=hidden]");
    
    if (checkbox.prop("checked") === true) {
      checkbox.prop("value", 0);
      hiddenField.prop("value", 0);
    } else if (checkbox.prop("checked") === false) {
      checkbox.prop("value", 1);
      hiddenField.prop("value", 1);
    }

    $(checkbox).trigger("change");
  });
};
```

It interacts with a switch component provided by the Materialize library. I have just added the final line, as there is some behaviour that needs to occur whenever a checkbox is triggered. But that change event never fires. I also have this function in my app:

```
const bindAllChecks = function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".select-all-check", function() {
    var checks = $(this).closest(".table, table").find(".multiple-check:visible");

    if (this.checked) {
      $.each( checks, function( index, checkbox ){
        if ($(checkbox).prop("checked") === false) {
          $(checkbox).prop("checked", true);
          $(checkbox).trigger("change");
        }
      });
    } else {
      $.each( checks, function( index, checkbox ){
        if ($(checkbox).prop("checked") === true) {
          $(checkbox).prop("checked", false);
          $(checkbox).trigger("change");
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Notice how I use the exact same `$(checkbox).trigger("change")`. In this function it works perfectly.

I've tried changing the order in which I bind the events, to make sure the change event is definitely defined beforehand. I've made sure that the rest of the function is being triggered correctly and that there are no issues in that regard. I've also tried different variations of alternative syntax, nothing has worked.

Here is the code it is supposed to trigger:

```
const bindCheckboxOverride = function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".checkbox-collection input[type=checkbox]:not(.select-all-check)", function() {
    var hiddenField = $(this).prev();

    if(hiddenField.attr("disabled") === "disabled") {
      hiddenField.removeAttr("disabled");
    } else  {
      hiddenField.attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: can you provide JsFiddle

Comment: @Satindersingh I don't think JsFiddle doesn't have the Materialize library unfortunately.

Comment: $(checkbox).trigger("change"); will trigger checkbox change event, where your checkbox change event code

Comment: @Satindersingh I've added the code to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't have an exact solution to the question I asked, but I have come up with an alternate method. Instead of trying the trigger a change, I have pulled out the functionality I want from the change even into its own function:

```
const bindCheckboxOverride = function() {
  $(document).on("change", ".checkbox-collection input[type=checkbox]:not(.select-all-check)", function() {
    handleCheckboxDisable(this);
  });
};

const handleCheckboxDisable = function(checkbox) {
  var hiddenField = $(checkbox).prev();

  if(hiddenField.attr("disabled") === "disabled") {
    hiddenField.removeAttr("disabled");
  } else  {
    hiddenField.attr("disabled", "disabled");
  }
};
```

So now I'm able to call this function directly from my other function:

```
const bindSwitches = function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".lever", function() {
    var checkbox = $(this).siblings("input[type=checkbox]");
    var hiddenField = $(this).siblings("input[type=hidden]");
    
    if (checkbox.prop("checked") === true) {
      checkbox.prop("value", 0);
      hiddenField.prop("value", 0);
    } else if (checkbox.prop("checked") === false) {
      checkbox.prop("value", 1);
      hiddenField.prop("value", 1);
    }

    handleCheckboxDisable(checkbox);
  });
};
```

It doesn't answer the question but I thought that may be of help to somebody. Would still like to know why the original code doesn't work if anybody has any insights.